# AttributeError 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'recv'

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all I need to say I've never tried coding in python before...

I'm trying to make a Twitch IRC bot working but I keep failing...

My bot.py code looks like this:

```
from src.lib import irc as irc_

from src.lib import functions_general

from src.lib import functions_commands as commands

from src.config import config

class PartyMachine:

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.irc = irc_.irc(config)
        self.socket = self.irc.get_irc_socket_object()


    def sock(self):
        irc = self.irc
        sock = self.socket
        config = self.config
        kage = sock

        while True:
            data = sock.recv(2048).rstrip()

            if len(data) == 0:
                pp('Connection was lost, reconnecting.')
                sock = self.irc.get_irc_socket_object()

            if config['debug']:
                print (data)
```

my config.py is here:

```
'socket_buffer_size': 1024
```

My irc.py is here:

```
def get_irc_socket_object(self):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(10)

    self.sock = sock

    try:
        sock.connect((self.config['server'], self.config['port']))
    except:
        pp('Cannot connect to server (%s:%s).' % (self.config['server'], self.config['port']), 'error')
        sys.exit()

    sock.settimeout(None)
def sock_send(sock, send, self):
    sock.send('USER %s\r\n' % self.config['username'], sock.encode('utf-8'), send.encode('utf-8'))
    sock.send('PASS %s\r\n' % self.config['oauth_password'])
    sock.send('NICK %s\r\n' % self.config['username'])

    if self.check_login_status(sock.recv(1024)):
        pp('Login successful.')
    else:
        pp('Login unsuccessful. (hint: make sure your oauth token is set in self.config/self.config.py).', 'error')
        sys.exit()
```

and my serve.py is here:

```
from sys import argv
from src.bot import *
from src.config.config import *

bot = PartyMachine(config).sock()
```

It keeps failing with "`AttributeError 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'recv'`". How can this be ?

Comment: Please post the full trace of the Exception, and indicate which line(s) of code are being referred to.

Comment: You're using the name `sock` for too many things.  Only have one thing for each identifier.  Where is `sock` defined?

Comment: @Bim Please be careful about fixing formatting in Python questions. In some cases you may inadvertently fix the actual problem. In this case you made an indentation change that was likely incorrect.

Comment: @glibdud Indeed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_irc_socket_object(self)` might be the problem. You call it with the line `self.socket = self.irc.get_irc_socket_object()`. This means that python expects the function `get_irc_socket_object(self)` to return a socket object, but you don't return anything (you just write `self.sock = sock`, which doesn't do anything because you use `self.socket` for the rest of your code). As a result, the function returns `none`, so now `self.socket` just has that as its value. Therefore, when you make the call to recv you get your error

Also, please clean up your variable names. Sock is used way too often in your code and makes it very hard to follow.